# Can LDA assign more than one topic for a word?

Tags: lda, topic-modeling

I have just started reading about Latent Dirichlet Allocation LDA and want to apply it to my project.

May I know if LDA is able to assign a topic to more than one word?

For example, Article A talks about "river banks" while Article B talks about "The role of banks in finance". Hence, will LDA allow the word "banks" to potentially be assigned to two different topics?

Answer (score 5):

LDA topics are probability distributions over terms.  Terms may have nonzero weight in any or all of the topics.  You can turn that around and find the probability of each topic given a specific term.  So yes, a term like "bank" can be assigned to many topics, but in general it will be assigned to some with a stronger weight than others.